# Remove Visibility of HTML Label using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, label

I have a label which initially I want not to display. As soon as Submit event of dialogue box happens I want to show this label with the resultant values. Initially the label is not visible which is correct. But onclick of submit button also it is not showing ..Here is my code..

HTML code for label..

```
<label class="button2" style="display:none" id="insert-data">&nbsp;Sites</label>
```

and here is my jquery script..

```
$('#insert-data').removeAttr('display');
        $('#insert-data').html(variable);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to remove a "display" attribute which doesn't exist. It's the `display` property of the `style` attribute. Use [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/):

```
$('#insert-data').html(variable).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#submit').click(function () {
            $('.button2').show();
        });
    });
```

also try this

```
 $('.button2').removeAttr('style');
```